Python to EXE SQLite "Unable to open database file"
I've created a small program that uses a UI - I used auto-py-to-exe with one-file to convert main.py and its retrospective modules into an exe file. However, when trying to launch the EXE I get an error. This is my first time creating an exe from a python file, so I'm most likely doing something wrong.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 378, in exec_module
  File "config\assets.py", line 47, in <module>
  File "config\assets.py", line 13, in __init__
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

SQLITE3 Error Message
The database is accessed with this bit of code:
class getImages():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        '''Creates a dictionary of dictionaries containing image data.

        Attributes:
            images: list of image data
        '''
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect("config\\data.sqlite")
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

I'm not entirely sure what the problem could be, maybe I'm using auto-py-to-exe incorrectly?
Here's the structure of the directory:
assets/
    fonts/
       inpin.ttf
config/
    assets.py
    data.sqlite
    module.py
    window.py
generator/
    scroll_area.py
modules/
    base/
        assets.py
        uploading.py
    boxArt/
        assets.py
        init.py
    magazineArt/
        assets.py
        init.py
    posterArt/
        assets.py
        init.py
obj.py
sql.py
main.py

I've tried just adding main.py to to auto-py-to-exe, I've tried adding each folder using --add-data with their files and I've also tried adding only the sqlite file to --add-data

The PROBLEM is that you are assuming that the application starts with the current directory set to the directory containing the script.  That is NOT the case.  You can do print(os.getcwd()) to prove that.  If you need directories relative to the script, then you have to COMPUTE that path using os.path.dirname(__file__).

"config\data.sqlite" looks like a relative path, if there is no such path underneath where you are running the program from then expect this error. if there is a "config" subdirectory but you don't have write permission to it then expect this error.
